# MouseLeftButtonUp Error

Tags: c#, windows-phone, mouseleftbuttonup

A few days ago I accidently did a replace on the Entire Solution - I was replace a MouseLEftButtonUp by _Tap. Now, even though I am doing a Tap event on an image in Windows Phone, I get the following error:

> Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.UIElement.MouseLeftButtonUp

Does anyone know how I can fix this? It's a very specific problem.

Comment: Could we see some XAML code from your image and the event handler you are using to handle the event. :)

Answer (score 2):

That is most likely due to the fact that the event signature of [UIElement.MouseLeftButtonUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttonup%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is different that [UIElement.Tap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.tap%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

The `MouseLeftButtonUp` uses a `MouseButtonEventHandler`, but the `Tap` requires a `EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>`, so you'll have to go to all your handlers and change the `MouseButtonEventArgs e` parameter to `EventArgs<GestureEventArgs> e`.